# Facebook Graph API: Events with no RSVP options

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api

Using Graph APIs from Android and iOS, I would like my app to send events to user's selected friends. However, I do not want the invitees to respond because the event is for information only. Is it possible to hide those (Join, May Be, and Decline) buttons when they see the event?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a feature of events; people invited to an event will always be able to choose their RSVP status for that event and see the other attendees. If this isn't what you want, don't use events for your app.